# select several averages of an interval

Tags: mysql, sql

So my coworker is looking at a schema which could be described as something like this:

```
+--------------------+-----------+
| DATETIME timestamp | INT value |
+--------------------+-----------+
```

Every 5 minutes a row is entered with the value for that moment.

Here's where it gets tricky. He wants to get the average of every 8 hour period within a 7 day interval.

Certainly, I can think of solutions which involve some client side code, we were wondering if it was possible to do more in SQL.

So in essence, he wants:

```
SELECT timestamp, value
  FROM table
 WHERE timestamp >= NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAYS 
   AND timestamp <= NOW();
```

And then breaking that up into 8 hour blocks, and averaging the contents of each block. (each block should have 12 rows, and there should be 3 blocks per day).

Comment: What database is this? From the look of your SQL, I'm guessing MySQL?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention, yes MySQL.

Comment: Do you want adjacent 8 hour blocks, or overlapping? 12:00 - 08:00, then 08:00 - 16:00, etc.  OR 12:00 - 08:00, then 12:05 - 08:05, 12:10 - 08:10, etc.

Comment: @njr101: I am assuming adjacent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
SELECT avg(`value`)
FROM `table`
WHERE timestamp >= NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY AND timestamp <= NOW()
group by concat(date(`timestamp`), case when hour(`timestamp`) between 0 and 7 then 1
                                        when hour(`timestamp`) between 8 and 15 then 2
                                        else 3 end)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not tied by only doing it in your request, you could try the following method of splitting the intervals before doing the request :

```
boundary1 = NOW()
boundary2 = NOW()

FOR i = 0 to 21 //7 days, 3 intervals of 8 hours per days
    boundary1 = boundary2
    boundary2 = boundary1 - seconds(8 hours)
    req = "SELECT timestamp, value FROM table WHERE timestamp >= "+boundary2+" AND timestamp <= "+boundary1
ENDFOR
```